# failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1

Tags: php

Всем привет подскажите в чем ошибка ибо при запуске пишет вот такую штуку

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents([https://api.telegram.org/botТОКЕН/sendmessage?chat_id=&text=text](https://api.telegram.org/bot%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%9A%D0%95%D0%9D/sendmessage?chat_id=&text=text)):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>   in C:\xamppp\htdocs\bot.php on line 13

```
<?php

$botTokken = "токен";
$website = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$botTokken.'';

$update = file_get_contents($website."/getupdates");

$updateArray = json_decode($update,true);

$chadId = $updateArray["result"][0]["message"]["chat"]["id"]; #chatId 
$text = $updateArray["result"][0]["message"]["chat"]["text"]; #chatId 

file_get_contents($website.'/sendmessage?chat_id='.$chatId.'&text=text');


print_r($chadId);

?>
```

Comment: проблема заключается в том что он не принимает данные из
$chadId = $updateArray["result"][0]["message"]["chat"]["id"]; #chatId 
$text = $updateArray["result"][0]["message"]["chat"]["text"]; #text
 как исправить?

Comment: последняя строка без переменной $text идет, должно быть так
file_get_contents($website.'/sendmessage?chat_id='.$chatId.'&text='.$text);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй заменить эти 2 строчки:

```
$chadId = $updateArray["result"][0]["message"]["chat"]["id"]; #chatId 
$text = $updateArray["result"][0]["message"]["chat"]["text"]; #chatId
```

на вот эти:

```
$chatId = $updateArray["result"][0]["message"]["chat"]["id"];
$text= $updateArray["message"]["text"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$botTokken = "токен";
$website = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$botTokken.'';

$update = file_get_contents($website."/getupdates");

$updateArray = json_decode($update,true);

$chadId = $updateArray["result"][0]["message"]["chat"]["id"]; #chatId 
$text = $updateArray["result"][0]["message"]["text"]; #text 
$text = $text;
$send = $website.'/sendmessage?chat_id='.$chadId.'&text='.$text.'';

file_get_contents($send);

print_r($text);
print_r($chadId);

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // начать повторы с интервалом 2 сек
var timerId = setInterval(function() {

}, 2000);

// через 5 сек остановить повторы
setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(timerId);
  window.location.href = "http://localhost:9180/bot.php"
}, 7000);

</script>
```